# How to connect docker SQL Server linux with SQL Operations Studio (in windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-data-studio

As I mentioned, I have not managed to connect the [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) to SQL Operations Studio.

I am using docker compose to mount the containers, this is created correctly, but when I enter the credentials in SQL Server Operations Studio, it does not connect.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  mssqllinux:
    image:  microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

    env_file: 
      - ./docker.env
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

docker.env

```
sa_password=RUc@ysd@f_P*yq4é
ACCEPT_EULA=Y
MSSQL_PID=Express
```

λ docker-compose ps

```
              Name                     Command           State           Ports
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    sqlserlinux_mssqllinux_1   /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr   Up      0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp
```

Connection:

---

[image: Connections settings]

The error:

---

[image: error message]

Error trace:

---

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de la red
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<TryGetConnection>b__0(Task`1 _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 298
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 542
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting from inside the container to make sure the service is up?

Comment: Actually, it could be this: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204 I don't have windows so not sure.

Comment: @chalo, did you find out what the problem was? +1.

Answer (score 2):

Several steps you can try.

First to remember, though you are inside of windows, but the database server is actually inside of Linux, and Linux is **super case sensitive** system. So, be sure your username is **SA or sa**.

Second thing is, in the server and port value, use a comma (,) instead of the colon (:), like below 
[image]

Third, if the above steps didn't work for you, first make sure you can access the server using SQLCMD tool. You can follow [this microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017#connectexternal) for details. After you can successfully login to the database, you can reuse the server value and credentials in SQL Operations Studio Window.

Hope this helps.